# Data attributes vs AJAX load

Tags: jquery, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I am working on a small todo PHP app. I am building my HTML with jQuery. One of the pieces is a button that launches a modal that would allow a user to edit the item. I am curious what the better approach is when it comes to loading the data:

1) add data attributes to each button during the initial load containing the data of the item and load those into the inputs when the 'edit' button is pressed

or

2) execute an AJAX call when the modal is launched, fetch the item from the database, and then load it into the inputs.

My gut tells me to go with option 1, but I figured I would ask and see what the community thinks about this topic

Comment: option 1 will be faster and more responsive than option 2, until a certain point where there's so much data in the DOM that the DOM becomes sluggish, or the page size is so large that it takes too long to download. I would lean more toward option 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do more of a hybrid of the two options, where each button has the `id` of the item, and once clicked it dynamically loads the data via AJAX. This would be the most scalable option (imagine a user who has 1000+ items or so)

It also really depends on what your max items per page is, length limits, *etc*..

Comment: yeah, I knew I'd need the ID as a data attribute. You had the exact same thought I did when it came to scalability, thanks!